# Where should I deliver the preparation data?

Tags: elite-dangerous

In every system not prepared by my the power I pledged to I can get up to 10 data. Where can I deliver this data? What should I do with that?

Comment: this may depend on the power you chose. Because the Power I'm in asks to *bring* prep data to the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on how your Power Prepares systems. Some Powers have you bring data from a system the Power owns to the desired uncontrolled system, while other powers have you take Prep data from the system into one of your own controlled systems, since that seems to be what you asked. here's how:

- open the navigation screen and set it to powerplay maps.
- Set the view to control (fortify)
- bring the preparation to one of those systems.

When a Control System receives 100 preparation data, it will become eligible for expansion, but your Power only has so much Command Capital (CC) to use per cycle. Expansion only begins on Control Systems that have the *most* preparation dumped into them, and the power can actually afford the expansion.

You can see the rankings preparation on the preparation tab in your power (or any other power for that matter). Preparing a system is a community chosen effort, if you dump all the prep data you can into a system you like, but nobody else in your power cares about it... The System probably won't start expansion.